# How do I get a ViewPager with focus to pass a dispatchKeyEvent() to its children views?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-viewpager

I have a dialog child view of a ViewPager that I have a setOnKeyListener() and setOnClickListener() setup. However, even when the child view is in visible focus (it's a dialog over the ViewPager) on the app, the listener never gets called on a key press. Further investigation seems to show that a ViewPager won't pass on the dispatchKeyEvent() if it has focus. However, if I set an OnKeyListener on the ViewPager with the code:

```
mViewPager.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
            && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {

            final int childIndex = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            mViewPager.getChildAt(childIndex).performClick();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The explicit click call on the child will activate the OnClickListener. However, I really shouldn't have to do that. The event should be passed down the view hierarchy. Is this the generally accepted way to deal with this? Having to explicitly call the child like this feels wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is intended behavior. In order for children to receive events, the ViewPager needs code to explicitly handle it. Part of this seems to be due to how even if a large list of views is given to the PageViewer, only a subset is usually actively cached and can have methods called on it. If I want all children to react to, let's say, a click, I would need to do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<mViewPager.getChildCount(); i++){
    mViewPager.getChildAt(i).performClick();
}
```

If your child Views have a OnClickListener set, then it will react to the clicks but only if that view is currently in the active ViewPager cache. If your Views has some kind of state that can be changed based on actions (like a new drawable appears on click and disappears with another click) then the only way to make all View children affected that I found seems to be that you need to have a controller that keeps track of the state and sets an OnPageChangeListener that iterates through the "active" children Views and ensures they are all in the proper state.